# Do you have to be spectating the win in Fortnite for it to count under Profile stats?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In a squad or duo game, if I leave the game and my team wins will it be counted? Or do I have to stay in the game and see the Winner Victory for it to be counted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game wont count if you leave, because you weren't part of the squad when they won

Comment: While this may be true if you quit out before you are killed, I think the OP was asking about if you leave the game *after* getting killed, based off the title.

Comment: @TimmyJim I'm pretty sure its the same thing, since the match is still being recorded and the final results aren't in if you leave, your current stats would be recorded, you get xp based on the match stats when you left, and if your squad ends up winning you don't get that xp for the quad winning, you get all rewards based on when you left the match